# UI5/OData: Providing Functionalites and Data depending on active User?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am relatively new to the UI5 Framework and I have a new use-case in my company that I want to implement with UI5 and OData Services.

Basically the application has two functionalities with different stakeholder:

- Role A is able to create new requirements
- Role B is able to check the requirements and update them with new
  information

How can I implement this the best way? My previous thoughts on that:

**Possibility 1:**

I have the OData Service in the Backend that is used by two separated application depending on the role. The access is controlled through the launchpad over the PCFG objects. So a specific user can only use the application that he actually needs. I believe that matches the basic granularity of Fiori apps. On the other hand, it invalidates the DRY principle since I would have redundant code like most of the view.

**Possibility 2:**

I check in the UI5 Framework or OData Service which user is currently using the app and enable/disable the required controls in the controller class. I haven’t come across on how to do this. Is there a way to check which user is logged on? Or how can I implement in the OData service, that only specific information is delivered to the client?

What is the correct way to implement such a use case? Is there a better option that I am not aware of? I would appreciate any thoughts on that matter, thanks :)

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

**Suggested Approach**
If two roles do not share any common functionalities, then I would go for two separate UI5 apps, so as to keep them simple. In that case, each app would have it's own OData service. But in the backend, you can always have a common class for 'Requirements' which is called by both the OData service implementations. (So as to maximize code reuse). So most of your business logic should be inside the 'Requirement' class, and the OData implementations serve as dispatchers.

**To check which user is logged in**
This is a common requirement for most of the business applications and it is possible in Gateway/ABAP as well. Within the ABAP context, there is always a system variable available named SY-UNAME, which will provide you the current logged in user's name. You can use it further to derive the user's role.

Comment: I agree with the logic has to be in the backend mostly, thanks.

Would it make sense to check the username with the SY-UNAME and depending on the user to return some kind of "role" object? The Fiori app could display specific fields depending on the returned object of the OData service.

Comment: Yes, you can do so. Again, as javascript validations can be easily tinkered with, you need to have further validation in the backend to ensure the user is not doing what he is not supposed to do.